# How to send email on order status change

Tags: orders, ce-1.9.0.1, order-status

I've created a function for mass order status change.

Here is my code:

```
public function NewMass1Action()
{
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countHoldOrder = 0;

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        if ($order->canHold()) {
            $order->masscustom1()
                ->save();
            $countHoldOrder++;
        }
    }

    if ($countHoldOrder) {
        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('%s order(s) have changed status.', $countHoldOrder));
    }

    $this->_redirectUrl(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/index'));
}
```

The problem is that this function is not sending an email to the customer when his order status is changed.

How can i make this function send an email for the status change?

Answer (score 4):

Source: http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/

---

**Create a file /app/etc/modules/Namespace_Custmail.xml with following content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Custmail>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Namespace_Custmail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**/app/code/community/Namespace/Custmail/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Custmail>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Namespace_Custmail>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <custmail>
                <class>Namespace_Custmail_Model</class>
            </custmail>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <mail_status_change>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>custmail/observer</class>
                        <method>invoicedStatusChange</method>
                    </mail_status_change>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
        <template>
            <email>
                <custom_order_tpl module="Namespace_Custmail">
                    <label>Status Mail Invoice</label>
                    <file>statusmail_processing.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </custom_order_tpl>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/community/Namespace/Custmail/Model/Observer.php**

```
class Namespace_Custmail_Model_Observer
{
    public function invoicedStatusChange($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            $this->_sendStatusMail($order);
    }

    private  function _sendStatusMail($order)
    {
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_tpl');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was holded');

        // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
        $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

        $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
    }
}
```

**/app/locale/en_US/template/email/statusmail_processing.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>Dear {{var username}}</h1>
    <p>Your order #{{var order_id}} was canceled for some reasons… </p>
    <div>{{var storename}} ({{var store_url}})</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

bellow code i have tested try it.

```
public function automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
        $orders->getSelect()->limit(1);  

        if ((int)$orders->count() !== 0) {
            return $this;
        }

        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW) {

            try {
                if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
                    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Custom_Invoicer: Order cannot be invoiced.', false);
                    $order->save();  
                }

                //START Handle Invoice
                $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

                $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                $invoice->register();

                $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);          
                $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically INVOICED by Custom_Invoicer.', false);

                $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    ->addObject($invoice)
                    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

                $transactionSave->save();

                //END Handle Invoice

                //START Handle Shipment
                //~ $shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
                //~ $shipment->register();
 //~ 
                //~ $order->setIsInProcess(true);
                //~ $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Automatically SHIPPED by Perception_Invoicer.', false);
 //~ 
                //~ $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                    //~ ->addObject($shipment)
                    //~ ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                    //~ ->save();
                //END Handle Shipment
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Custom_Invoicer: Exception occurred during automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder action. Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
                $order->save();
            }                
        }

    return $this;        
    }
```

**I hope this will help you.**